# distinct inner join hql

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I've the following hibernate entities

```
public class Container {
  ...

  @OneToMany
  private List<ACLEntry> aclEntries;
}
```

For securing my container instances i use the following entity:

```
public class ACLEntry {

  ...
  private Long sid;
  private boolean principal;
  private Integer mask;

}
```

The hql-queries will be created automatically so for searching container instances, 
the following query will be created:

```
select container from Container container 
inner join container.aclEntries as aclEntry 
with bitwise_and (aclEntry.mask, 1) = 1 and 
   (aclEntry.sid = :userId or aclEntry.sid = :roleId)
```

The problem with this is, that the aclentry join could return 2 results which will result in duplicate container results.

Has anyone an idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood the problem you need a container that can hold multiple entries of your Container object just replace your hql query with the following one:

With adding `select distinct` as native query.

Comment: We use an internal query engine to build hql queries, so i cannot add distinct because it would affect all queries. I think the the distinct should only applied to the join, or am i wrong ?

Comment: +1. This is the right and simple solution. If the query engine can't handle it, then improve the query engine.

Answer (score 0):

As a brute force solution, you could write a native query.

Comment: we are using an internal query engine to build our hql queries, changing to native queries we would have to change our query engine

Answer (score 0):

It might make more sense to write this as a Criteria query, which [easily supports selecting an object based on conditions of it's associations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations).

The same thing can be done in HQL or a native query, it might be instructive to execute a Criteria query specifying the same logic and just see what HQL/SQL it generates.

Comment: as mentioned in the docs the criteria api would execute two queries and then joins the results in a third step; i think for this case it would not perform enough for fetching large resultsets, or am i wrong ?